# Ag-grid Date filter disables after input

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid

I have a date filter on a column in ag-grid, the filter works correctly and filters out the correct dates, however after it's filtered for the given input it disables the box so the user can't change the date filter within the floating filter box.
I can see that this is not the expected behavior from the examples in the docs but I can't figure out why it's doing this as I get no errors in the console.

Here is the column definition:

```
{ headerName: 'Date', field: 'date', sortingOrder: this.sortingOrder, valueFormatter: this.dateFormatter,
                cellClassRules: oddRule, filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',
                filterParams: { browserDatePicker: true, comparator: this.dateComparator } },
```

Any help really appreciated!

Comment: can you share your code in stackblitz?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Simonare, I started the stackblitz and realised it was due to the version of ag-grid, it's working fine with v17 but upgrading to v18 causes the issue